# haxm installer not compatible with windows and adv error 0x60000000

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have install Android Studio 2.2.3 but I cant install haxm, in the Android SDK manager I get "installer not compatible with windows" and when I try to use AVD i get:
"cannot launch avd in emulator. output: emulator: warning: userdata partition is resized from 550 m to 800 m error: resizing partition e2fsck failed with exit code 1 hax is enabled hax ram_size 0x60000000 hax is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. emulator: listening for console connections on port: 5554 emulator: serial number of this emulator (for adb): emulator-5554"

I have Lenovo ideapad 310-15IBK laptop with  intel core i5-7200U CPU and windows 10 home 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You must enable virtualization technology.

1.go to control panel

2.go to programs and features

3.click on "turn windows feature on or off" a prompt box will be appear()

4.unmark the checkbox of Hyper-v.

As shown below:
[image]

restart your system and press the delete button.

You have to go to bios.

You should look in the BIOS to follow one of the following options to enable them.

Intel Virtualization Technology.

Intel VT-x.

Virtualization Extensions.

Vanderpool.

[image]

Comment: Mahdi my friend, 1. I have already enable the virtualization in the BIOS, 2. I don't have hyper-v on my laptop (it's Windows 10 home)

Answer (score 0):

> I cant install haxm, in the Android SDK manager I get "installer not
>   compatible with windows"

try to install Haxm in AVD manager and create virtual device and in that page u see install Haxm if you haven't already install it!!!

[image]

if you face error, click show details to see what's wrong and send us. for example i didn't have admin privilage so Haxm wouldn't install for all user and it caused an error.

[image]